# only border transition on hover 90 deg around

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuove.jpg)

please tell me anybody in above image when cursor on it hover automatic rotate border only in above image is it possible by css if possible give a code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is not a place where people write code for you. Show [what you've tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) already. Include at least an outline, but preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem (including a traceback if present). Also refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect you want like this:

```css
*,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(//unsplash.it/400/400);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 15px solid lightgrey;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 15px solid steelblue;
}

.circle:hover::after {
  animation: spin .75s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with animation when hover element.

You can see example here it's the same idea.

Example :- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp